# Масштабирование картинок?

Tags: jquery, масштабирование, javascript, html, css

Наглядный пример масштабирования картинки при изменении окна браузера - [просто картинка](http://www.apple-reviews.com/wp-content/uploads/iphone-5.jpg). Попробуйте поизменять окно браузера (я тестил в опере, хроме, ИЕ8 и мозилле): дело в том, что если расширяешь окно или сужаешь его по ширине, то ширина фото (аттрибут **width**) как бы стоит на месте, но если окно уменьшаешь или увеличиваешь по высоте, то фото масштабируется, т.е. изменяются оба атрибута **width** и **height** фотки (*это не **css***!). Как достичь такого эффекта, если я, например, в div какой-то обособленный положу на экране фотку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вашу задачу. Сделал изменение ширины картинки пропорционально изменению ширины окна браузера. Высоту, если надо, вычисляйте по аналогии. [Посмотреть пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rjbPj/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Изменяйте размер окна</p>
    <span></span>
</div>
<img src="http://www.apple-reviews.com/wp-content/uploads/iphone-5.jpg" alt="" />
```

CSS

```
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #900;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
var pS = $(window).width() / 100;
var imgW = $('img').width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    var percentW = $(this).width() / pS;
    var newWidth = parseInt(imgW / 100 * percentW,10);
    $('img').css('width', newWidth + 'px');
    $('span').text('Текущая ширина картинки: ' + newWidth + 'px');
});
```

Comment: ну да в полне что-то подобное, только у вас наоборот немного, когда сужаешь, тогда width и height изменяетя, но это мелочи, главное чтобы пропорции сохранялись в любом окне браузера (любом браузере), ну и глобально - на любом устройстве, т.е. чтобы это адекватно выглядело даже на мобильном.

Comment: Ммм... Вродк, как изменяются размеры и когда сужаешь окно, и когда расширяешь.

Answer (score 0):

Для картинки, которую вы привели в качестве примера, используется мета-тег
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height" />

Comment: а на сколько этот метатег можно применить в "обычной ситуации"?

Comment: [Тут вы сможете почитать про Meta viewport](http://interpretor.ru/iphone_dev)